# Azure Webapp Java Rest API endpoints does not work

Tags: java, azure, rest, spring-boot

I have an REST API with enpoint form/get and form/post. I have made a pipeline and deployed it to azure web app. Deployment seems to be good but I can't access the endpoints. I get 404 back. In my head the endpoint for https://my-webapp.azurewebsites.net/form/get would work but it does not. Am I missing something? Could it be that I need to configure the endpoints somewhere on azure portal?

Comment: Have you verified the endpoints having access on your local machine?

Comment: Yes, they are working.

Comment: enable the logs, probably there's some error during the startup

Comment: Shared some troubleshooting ways in my answer. If it is helpful, please mark it as accepted which may help others further. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can create an [`Azure DevOps Project`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/devops-projects/) from Azure portal.

[image]

You can choose to start with a java spring application. This will create a new DevOps project for you along with build pipeline and release pipeline in it. You can take the start project as a sample for configuring yours.

2. You can use `Advanced tools` manage you web app.

[image]

Under the Kudu tools page, you can check the environment, manage app files, monitor processes and so on.

[image]